# Custom Seekbar view issue in android Marshmallow (6.0)

Tags: android, seekbar

I having issue in seekbar in android Marshmallow (6.0)

following is the seekbar view

```
<SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/SeekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:max="100"
            android:maxHeight="11dp"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/styled_progress_seekbar"
            android:thumb="@drawable/popularity_box"
            android:indeterminate="false" />
```

and custom progressDrawable resource is

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/blue_dot_new"
        android:tileMode="mirror" />
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/grey_dot_new"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
</item>
```

i haven't included my 9 patch image here.

following is the output what i am getting in pre Lollipop (working fine)

[image]

but i having issue in Marshmallow and output is

[image]

Many thanks,

Nandakishore P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i resolved the issue by increasing android:maxHeight="50dp" and changing 9 patch image.